# Swift - Horizontal UIPickerView

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I'm trying to make a Horizontal Picker using Swift by rotating the UIPickerView and then rotating the label inside it, I tried also rotating the view inside it, instead of the label.

But in both ways I have the same result as shown in the image, the labels inside the picker are still not displayed as it is supposed to be.

Please take a look at the photo and the code,
any ideas on how to fix this?

[image: Horizontal Picker]

```
@IBOutlet weak var myPicker: UIPickerView!
var rotationAngle: CGFloat!
var pickerArray: [String] = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    rotationAngle = -90 * (.pi/180)
    myPicker.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rotationAngle)

    self.myPicker.delegate = self
    self.myPicker.dataSource = self

    pickerArray = ["Hello", "World", "What", "Where", "When", "How", "Hey", "Welcome", "Good", "Ok", "Bye", "World!"]

    rotatePickerView(pickerView: myPicker)

}
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerArray.count
}

internal func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerArray[row]
}

func rotatePickerView(pickerView : UIPickerView) {

    myPicker.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rotationAngle)
    myPicker.frame = CGRect(x: -150, y: myPicker.frame.origin.y, width: view.frame.width + 300, height: 200)
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 24)
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .regular)
    label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.textColor = UIColor.black
    label.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 90 * (.pi / 180 ))

    label.text = pickerArray[row]

    return label
}
```

Comment: check by decreasing font size

Comment: That is not a font size issue.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify the frame for your label i.e. its width and height.
You need to specify the frame of the label when initializing and the height of the view through the delegate function.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    
    let pickerRow = UIView()
    pickerRow.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    let rowLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    rowLabel.textColor = .black
    rowLabel.text = yourData[row]
    rowLabel.textAlignment = .center
    pickerRow.addSubview(rowLabel)
    pickerRow.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 90 * (.pi/180))
    return pickerRow
}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
```